# tslint CLI and jest CLI not working on iterm zsh macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, zsh, tslint

Even after globally installing tslint, typescript, tslint CLI does not seem to work on i-term zsh on macOS. When I try to use it, it says

```
zsh: command not found: tslint
```

However when added to package json of a node project as

```
"fix": "tslint --fix --project ."
```

and run

```
yarn fix
```

it seems to run properly. I tried looking up npm global prefix by typing

```
npm config get prefix
```

it points to a

```
usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0
```

All other binaries like node works and the bin folder has tslint in it which mean that it should actually work but it doesn't seem to. Even jest CLI doesn't seem to work but when added to package.json of a project works properly.

I can't see why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem again and was bent to solve it as it was bothering me. This answer might be like the A,B,C of shell but I am sure it will help beginners like me.

So, when we install any library which is executable on terminal ( CLI basically ), the shell needs to know where that binary file is stored. In short, we need to tell our shell that let's say there is a CLI named `sapphire` which you want to run on your terminal, the shell must know where is the binary file of sapphire which is to be run. Shell knows this via the `$PATH` environment variable which is specified in the `.zshrc`(If you use zsh as shell) or `.bashrc`(If you use bash as your shell) file in your home directory.

In order to know which paths are included in `$PATH` ( meaning where does your shell look in case of a command run ), run this

```
echo $PATH
```

and check where did npm install the package globally. This is easy as npm prompts where it installed the files. An example would be this

[image]

Now simple check whether `$PATH` has this path included in it or not ( by this path, I mean where binary of grunt has been installed `/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/bin/grunt`. If it has it, `grunt` will work smooth and if this path is not included in $PATH variable in your .zshrc/.bashrc file, you will get an error like

```
zsh: command not found: grunt
```

All you have to do to solve this is include this path in $PATH and you are good to go.

How to make changes in `.zshrc`?

Open the file using vim or subl. Make the necessary changes. Either close terminal and open again or restart the shell by running `$SHELL`. Things will get reflected.